# How do I wire up a custom C# ASP.Net WebControl to post back a custom __EVENTARGUMENT?

Tags: asp.net, event-handling, custom-controls, postback, web-controls

I'm creating a custom ASP.Net GridView and I want to be able to alter the __EVENTARGUMENT value but I can't figure out how to capture the returned value on the server side.

I'm creating the ability to have a collapsible representation, so the first level is the standard GridView and I will insert additional rows via JavaScript if they expand the first level row.

My problem is how to create a link on the selecond level rows that posts back with custom data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the RaisePostBackEvent is where this value gets passed into; the base GridView class allows you to override it, so you should be able to tap into it there.

This is a part of the IPostBackEventHandler interface.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Use __dopostback to raise the postback from javascript. Use the correct parameters so that this will be mapped to the right event

Comment: That doesn't work for custom events. There's no way to map the __EVENTARGUMENT to your event without capturing the value in the event Brian referenced and directing it yourself.